# Richard Hooker meaning

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence from Richard Hooker mean? "Unto kings by human right, honour by very divine right, is due."

Comment: Please share what you think it might mean, where the point of confusion lies, etc.

Comment: If you find the quote in Google and examine it in context, it's still gibberish.  There is no way to give a meaning without examining the literary analysis (that is available on the internet, if you look).

Answer (score 1):

He meant that whoever is put in charge by the laws of humans is also in charge by divine right, i.e. in his eyes God wants humans to follow their kings, even if it was not God personally who sat them on the throne.

The sentence going before makes this very clear: "[...] neither was Tiberius Caesar by especial commission from Heaven therewith invested; and yet payment of tribute unto Caesar, being now made Emperor, is the plain Law of Jesus Christ:"

Answer (score 0):

He is asserting the Divine Right of Kings:

[See exhaustive Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_right_of_kings)

Essentially, Hooker is saying that people have to respect kings because God has appointed them.